# WPF: How to draw a circle?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I have the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Shapes;

Arc a = new Arc();
a.ArcThicknessUnit = Microsoft.Expression.Media.UnitType.Pixel;
a.ArcThickness = 10;
a.StrokeThickness = 1;
a.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
a.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkMagenta);
a.StartAngle = 0;
a.EndAngle = 360;
a.Width = 200;
a.Height = 200;
a.Stretch = Stretch.None;
_myStackPanel.Children.Add(a);

DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
dt.Tick += (s, e) => { a.StartAngle = a.StartAngle + 4; };
dt.Start();
```

When it is executed I get an "erasable circle". I need to get the opposite effect. Сircle drawing effect. How can I change the code to get a "drawn circle"? [Circle Drawning Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuSvu.gif)

Comment: How about animating EndAngle instead of StartAngle? Also note that Windows timers don't have millisecond precision. Something like `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: OK. Thank you! Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `EndAngle` instead of the `StartAngle`:

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Shapes;

Arc a = new Arc();
a.ArcThicknessUnit = Microsoft.Expression.Media.UnitType.Pixel;
a.ArcThickness = 10;
a.StrokeThickness = 1;
a.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
a.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkMagenta);
a.StartAngle = 0;
a.EndAngle = 0;//Start as 0
a.Width = 200;
a.Height = 200;
a.Stretch = Stretch.None;
_myStackPanel.Children.Add(a);

DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
dt.Tick += (s, e) => { a.EndAngle = a.EndAngle + 4; };//update EndAngle
dt.Start();
```